# Creating a layout to draw cells with colors like in a defrag program using android

Tags: android, view, grid, android-gridview

I have been looking for info about which could be the best way to draw a view like the ones shown in drefrag programs. An example con be found [here](http://imgs.2000shareware.com/screenshots/o_amp_o_defrag_server_edition_14485.gif).

My first attempt was to use a grid layout but it seems that could be slow for a big ammount of cells. My maximum could be between 150-200 cells.

Could anyone that has dealt with this problem share his/her experiences or suggest a better way to achieve it?.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a [SurfaceView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html) which I would draw on. 
You might be able to use a TableView and change the background of the cells, but I am not sure if that is possible.

Comment: I was poking around the idea of a surfaceview too, but I always prefer to avoid them in complex layouts (the grid is shown beside a lot of other UI elements) because I have had bad experiences with it in the past related to resizing, etc...

Comment: How coud there be resizing?

Comment: Resizing could occur for example if you are using not explicits sizes like the "0dp" thing and you insert later a new view into the layout. In my case this happens when an Ad Banner is inserted when it arrives.